# Read a cookie value in portal_normal.vm using path attribute

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui, liferay-velocity

I am trying to get the cookies value in portal_normal.vm of my custom liferay theme.

At first I am setting a cookie value on click event using JavaScript.
In some pages I able to get the cookies in theme but some pages I am not able to get the cookie value,but when I check in f12 cookies it is present.

Below is code for setting cookie using JavaScript:

```
  $('.close').click(function(){
   document.cookie = "cookie_set=true;path=/";
   $('.close').attr("data-dismiss","alert");
  });
```

Liferay custom theme to get the cookie:

```
 #foreach($cookie in $request.getCookies())
      #if ($cookie.getName() eq "cookie_set")
            #set($previousWeb = $cookie.getValue())
      #end
```

Problem here is I am able to get the cookie value in some pages.

Can any one help me out?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Are you trying to show something only once based on cookie value?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

[JS Cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)